# Angular 1.4.1 $cookies ending up as session cookies

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am having a problem setting persistent cookies under Angular 1.4.1   The cookies always end up (according to Chrome's resource inspection, and the more obvious effect of closing the browser and reopening the page) as session cookies.

```
   $scope.HideSystemNotice = function() {
           // set expiry 1 yr in the future - well after System Notice expires
           var now = new Date(),
               exp = new Date(now.getFullYear()+1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate())
           $cookies.put(  'Snotice'+$scope.SystemNoticeInfo[0].snid, // cookiename
                          'dismissed',                               // value
                          { 'expires': exp }                         // expiry
                       );
           $scope.NextSystemNotice();
   };
```

This is essentially the same as the examples provided elsewhere on StackOverflow (but I lack the rep to add to those convos :( thus the separate question)

The cookies are being set - I can see them show in Chrome's resource view.   However, they have no expiry date (Chrome shows them as "session").

What obvious tidbit have I missed in setting the date?  Thanks.

Edit....

I'm still having problems setting an expiry date.  I've upgraded to Angular 1.4.7 now, and have tried using the $cookiesProvider defaults in a .config to no benefit

```
app.config(function($cookiesProvider) {
 var n = new Date();
 $cookiesProvider.defaults = {
    path: '/',
    domain: location.hostname,
    secure: true,
    expires: new Date(n.getFullYear()+1, n.getMonth(), n.getDate())
 };
});
```

then further down in the code:

```
    $scope.HideSystemNotice = function() {
        $cookies.put('Snotice'+$scope.SystemNoticeInfo[0].snid, 'dismissed');
        $scope.NextSystemNotice();
    };
```

And I'm still only seeing session cookies being created.

The Path and Domain are correct, however the cookie is not being tagged as secure, so it is like the Options (or in the latest incarnation, defaults) are not being applied (I dont seem to need to set path or domain, they get set regardless).

Can someone point out what is incorrect in either piece of code?

Comment: That code seems like it would work properly, are you sure you are using angular 1.4?

Comment: unless google is lying to me

       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem and now found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12081). The thing is, you shouldn't create a new object (assigning `{...}` to `defaults`), but just edit the properties of the `defaults` object like this:

```
app.config(function($cookiesProvider) {
    var n = new Date();
    $cookiesProvider.defaults.path = '/';
    $cookiesProvider.defaults.domain = location.hostname;
    $cookiesProvider.defaults.secure = true;
    $cookiesProvider.defaults.expires = new Date(n.getFullYear()+1, n.getMonth(), n.getDate());
});
```

Comment: **face palm** now that I read that, and the link, it does seem obvious...  why would I think to create a new defaults object - they're defaults - they have to exist already...   The AngularJS docs should provide your example :)